# Remove specified main Element from divs with different id

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I want to remove element with "X" button, but these elements has different ids and goes into the infinit. How should i do? I want to remove the main "Div". Ex. the "blacklisttab1" because i want to close it, but i can't because it has different id.

I know, in my recent "closefunc" function is removing more elements. But i want to remove only one specified element.

I just tried more ways to do it, but I'm stuck here, and I decided to ask for help.

```js
function closetab() {
  var tab = document.getElementById("listtab");
  tab.parentElement.removeChild(tab);
}

function closefunc() {
  var blackitems = document.getElementsByClassName("blacklisttab");
  for (var i = 0; i <= blackitems.length; i++) {
    var tab = document.getElementById("blacklisttab" + i);
    tab.remove(tab)
```

```css
.fragment {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  height: 20px;
  border: px solid blue;
  color: blue;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#close {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bl {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.closebtn {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}


#closebutn {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="blacklisttab0">
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="bltab">
    <span onclick="closetab();" class="closebtn">x</span>
    <div class="blacklistitem" id="blacklistitem">
      <p class="blacklistitempgraph" id="blacklistitempgraph0">DNFB</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="blacklisttab1">
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="bltab">
    <span onclick="closetab();" class="closebtn">x</span>
    <div class="blacklistitem" id="blacklistitem">
      <p class="blacklistitempgraph" id="blacklistitempgraph1">HIM</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="blacklisttab2">
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="bltab">
    <span onclick="closetab();" class="closebtn">x</span>
    <div class="blacklistitem" id="blacklistitem">
      <p class="blacklistitempgraph" id="blacklistitempgraph2">CFOs</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="blacklisttab3">
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="bltab">
    <span onclick="closetab();" class="closebtn">x</span>
    <div class="blacklistitem" id="blacklistitem">
      <p class="blacklistitempgraph" id="blacklistitempgraph3">Reduce</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicking a `.closebtn` element should remove the ancestor `blacklisttab` element from the document? Or just hide it?

Comment: First of all, it was made to hide it, but i want to develope it to eliminate the element from the document.

Comment: You cannot and should not have multiple elements with the same ID. ID is supposed to be unique per element. Use class to assign same class to multiple elements. Which function is supposed to work? closetab() or closefunc()?

Comment: closefunc(), because it's working, but it's deleting multiple tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest, following clarification in the comments that you seem to want to remove the ancestor `.blacklisttab` elements on clicking the descendant `.closebtn` element:

```
// using a named function, in this case using Arrow syntax;
// passing in the event object ('e') from the (later)
// EventTarget.addEventListener() method:
const removeTab = (e) => {

  // retrieving the element that was clicked:
  let affected = e.target,

  // finding the closest ancestor element matching
  // the supplied CSS selector:
      ancestor = affected.closest('.blacklisttab');

  // removing that element from the DOM, using
  // ChildNode.remove():
  ancestor.remove();
}

// using document.querySelectorAll() to find all elements
// matching the supplied CSS selector, and calling
// NodeList.forEach() to iterate over that NodeList:
document.querySelectorAll('.closebtn').forEach(

  // using Arrow function expressions to bind the
  // removeTab() function (note the deliberate lack
  // of parentheses) as the event-handler for the
  // 'click' event:
  (close) => close.addEventListener('click', removeTab)
);
```

```js
const removeTab = (e) => {
  let affected = e.target,
      ancestor = affected.closest('.blacklisttab');

  ancestor.remove();
}

document.querySelectorAll('.closebtn').forEach(
  (close) => close.addEventListener('click', removeTab)
);
```

```css
.fragment {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  height: 20px;
  border: px solid blue;
  color: blue;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#close {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bl {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.closebtn {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#closebutn {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="blacklisttab0">
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment">
    <span class="closebtn">x</span>
    <div class="blacklistitem">
      <p class="blacklistitempgraph">DNFB</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="blacklisttab1">
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment">
    <span class="closebtn">x</span>
    <div class="blacklistitem">
      <p class="blacklistitempgraph">HIM</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="blacklisttab2">
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment">
    <span class="closebtn">x</span>
    <div class="blacklistitem">
      <p class="blacklistitempgraph">CFOs</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 bordered bl blacklisttab" id="blacklisttab3">
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment">
    <span class="closebtn">x</span>
    <div class="blacklistitem">
      <p class="blacklistitempgraph">Reduce</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that you should not, in any circumstance, use the same `id` for multiple elements. With that in mind I've removed the duplicate `id`s from your elements in order that you're left with valid HTML.

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: I accept your advices, very useful. I attached my other functions into the site, now everything is working very well. Thank you, i appreciate your patiance and your help.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help!